# How can I get the column/row of the cell that I found using an Excel script on VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am a complete excel script beginner, and I found something that is like below that searches for a word and replaces it.

```
Sub replacerev()
What = InputBox("word to search")
repl = InputBox("word to replace")

Cells.replace What:=What, Replacement:=repl, LookAt:=xlPart, _
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
ReplaceFormat:=False
End Sub
```

What I would like is searching for a word, and then finding its column/row. I can't quite figure out how to do that even with research.

Comment: Can't have researched very hard, first result for "excel search vba": http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?634644-Excel-Find-Method-in-Excel-VBA-(Any-version-of-Excel)  -- look at the second code block.

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9463171/how-to-search-on-worksheet-by-vba-code

Comment: And this http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/

Comment: @Orbling: Just noticed the 1st link :P