# Populating a Table from Multiple Data Sets in Excel with Only Fields that Have Values

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, dynamic-arrays

I want to create a table that populates from multiple tables, but only for the columns that have values.

For example:

User 1 from table 1 (T1: User 1) has:

- 2 Apples
- 1 Bananas
- 0 Pears
- Total Fruit: 3

User 2 from table 1 (T1: User 2) has:

- 0 Apples
- 0 Bananas
- 2 Pears
- Total Fruit: 2

User 1 from table 2 (T2: User 1) has:

- 3 Apples
- 1 Bananas
- 1 Pears
- Total Fruit: 5

This would populate the table with T1: User 1's data, then T1: User 2's data, then T2: User 1's data.

But if User 2 had a 0 total, the table would exclude User 2's data in the table and would populate the column with T2: User 1's data after T1: User 1's data.

[image: Example]

I'm looking to dynamically merge multiple tables of data that excludes instances where the total is 0. As an additional wrinkle, this table should have no blank columns, so it lists each instance that has data one after the next.

I've been experimenting with extremely long nested IF statements, but I'm not sure if there's a more elegant approach to this scenario.

Comment: Would love to help but don't know where to start as I need more info/understanding.

Can you elaborate, e.g. show your expected results? And maybe show what the tables look like according to your example? And examples of your nested if statements?

Comment: Let me see if I can clarify a bit.


Ex.


There are two tables - Each instance (User) on the table has a count of each fruit for the instance and a total of fruit for the instance. I want to combine these tables into a third table, but omit any instances where the total is zero and leave no blank spaces. 


I want to populate the table just as normal spreadsheet columns, with the User as the header, then the breakdown, then the total - columns listing next to each other with no blank columns.

I've tried using nested IF statements to do this, but it's quickly becoming unwieldy.

Comment: For each cell - IF total > 0, use the first instance from table 1, ELSE use the Total of first instance from table 2 if greater than 0 -> Next cell, if Total > 0, use the second instance from Table 1, ELSE use the first instance from Table 2 if its Total > 0. And so on - It's really not a great solution, and I can already see it's not going to get the proper results. I hope this helps clarify somewhat.

Comment: I think your problem is the underlying data structure. The way the tables are set up currently, you need a macro to go through each table and decide whether or not to include it in the resulting table.
 
If it is feasible to alter your underlying data so that it has four columns: _OriginalTable_, _User_, _Fruit_ and _Amount_, then it is only a matter of creating a simple pivot table (or summary table using formulas). Is this something you could do?

Answer (score 0):

If you are starting from SQL tables, you can use SSIS to get only what you need. Please let us know what is your source.

Answer (score 0):

There's no Excel function to do that simply.

Using [Excel-VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba) is the way to go. Learn by using tutorials. We won't do your work assignment for you.

Maybe a place to start:

[How to search on worksheet by VBA Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9463171/how-to-search-on-worksheet-by-vba-code/9465060#9465060)